# How to do convert a collection of XPathNavigator objects to a XPathNodeIterator

Tags: c#, xml, xpathnavigator, xpathnodeiterator

How do I convert a collection of [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx) objects into a collection of [XPathNodeIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx) objects?

Below is a sample code:

```
public XPathNodeIterator RandomizeXPathNodeIterator(XPathNodeIterator iterator)
{
    List<XPathNavigator> list = new List<XPathNavigator>();
    //Populate list with XPathNavigator's

    //How do i return XPathNodeIterator
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert from XPathNavigator to XPathNodeIterator? What can you accomplish with a XPathNodeIterator but not a XPathNavigator?